Chrome extension developed with Vite react and js routing problem
For some resoning i have been struggling with routing in Chrome extension
The problem is about redirecting users based on their authentication status in a React application using React Router. Specifically, the issue is ensuring that when the user is not authenticated (i.e., user is null), they are redirected to the Onboarding page, while authenticated users are directed to the main application routes.
 import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  RouterProvider,
  createHashRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Navigate,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Onboarding from "./pages/Onboarding";
import SplashScreen from "./components/SplashScreen/SplashScreen";
import ScreenTwo from "./components/Onboarding/ScreenTwo";
import ScreenThree from "./components/Onboarding/ScreenThree";
import RootLayout from "./components/layouts/RootLayout";
import AlarmPage from "./pages/alarm/AlarmPage";

const router = createHashRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <RootLayout />,
    children: [
      { path: "/", element: <Home /> },
      { path: "/alarm/alarmpage", element: <AlarmPage /> },
    ],
  },
  { path: "/onboarding", element: <Onboarding /> },
  { path: "/screentwo", element: <ScreenTwo /> },
  { path: "/screenthree", element: <ScreenThree /> },
]);

const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check user data in chrome.storage or any other authentication method
    const userData = localStorage.getItem("user");
    if (userData) {
      setUser(JSON.parse(userData));
    } else {
      setUser(null);
    }
  }, []);

  console.log(user);

  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router}>
      <Routes>
        {user === null ? (
          <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/onboarding" replace />} />
        ) : (
          <>
            <Route path="/*" element={<RootLayout />} />
            <Route path="/onboarding" element={<Onboarding />} />
            <Route path="/screentwo" element={<ScreenTwo />} />
            <Route path="/screenthree" element={<ScreenThree />} />
          </>
        )}
      </Routes>
    </RouterProvider>
  );
};

export default App;

all i am getting is just
<RootLayout> 
   <Home /> 
<RootLayout />

it is not Navigating to onboarding page if user === null
